# can't install xcode, issue with MobileDevice.pkg

Tags: macos, xcode

I am trying to install xcode on my mac version : Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 But I'm having a problem,

i download xcode version 4.6.2 from Appstore after i installed the app i clicked on the icon in the launchpad and it just opened and ask me to install device support so i click install and it ask for my password so i entered the pass and it wrote:

An unknown error occurred. See the install log for more details.

so i looked for this problem and i found that i can go to xcode icon, click on the option and click on "Show Package Contents" and than on Contents->Resources->Packages than i click "MobileDevice.pkg", again i entered my password and nothing happend like really nothing, the password is right and i dont know why it is like that

thank you for your help ilan.

Comment: What error?  something like this? com.apple.SecurityServer: Failed to authorize right 'system.install.app-store-software' by client '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/installd' [1063] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app' [1348]

Comment: Did you verify that you are logged in as Administrator in System Preferences > Users and Groups, it should say Admin under your name.

Comment: yes i'm under admin user

Comment: about the error, where i can find the error? in the install log?

Comment: Yes you can find it in there or in the Console.

Comment: this is what i have in the install.log:

Jun 11 01:27:06 ilan-finkels-MacBook-Pro crsud[17445]: crsud: Starting
Jun 11 01:27:06 ilan-finkels-MacBook-Pro crsud[17445]: crsud: Exiting.
Jun 11 05:27:06 ilan-finkels-MacBook-Pro crsud[19040]: crsud: Starting
Jun 11 05:27:06 ilan-finkels-MacBook-Pro crsud[19040]: crsud: Exiting.

Comment: and this on "all messages"
6/11/13 9:16:30.804 AM authorizationhost: SFBuiltinEntitled: Xcode.app is not entitled for system.install.apple-software

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue in another post but not certain if the errors you are getting are the same but here it is. Source is provided below:

Use Pacifist to install MobileDevice.pkg!!!
Simply open the file with pacifist 
click the top right Lock button that says Not Authorized 
Type your password
and hit install
once thats done install itunes normally
or with pacifist worked great for me

SOURCE:
http://www.tonymacx86.com/general-help/98821-xcode-itunes-mobiledevice-pkg-fix.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I followed the answer to the question here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3863980?start=0&tstart=0

That fixed it.